# Is it possible to fire an event when SoftKeyboard is open

Tags: android

I want to notify (event listener) when the Softkey board is opened or closed in the android ? is it possible ?
if possible tell me the way please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  setContentView(mView);
  mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int heightDiff = mView.getRootView().getHeight()
                        - (r.bottom - r.top);
        if (heightDiff > 100) {
        //Keybord Action change
                    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve like this :

```
public static InputMethodManager imm = null;
            if(!(imm==null)){

            imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,1);

            // here do whatever you want to do
            }else
            {


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect if keyboard is currently open:

```
InputMethodManager imm = 
    (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

//keyboard is visible       
if(imm != null) {
    //do something, e.g., hide the keyboard like so : 
    //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    //or fire an event like so:
    //mButton.performClick();
} else {
    //do something
}
```